# Construct the grammar that generates the given languange

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammar

Find a grammar that generates this language :
L = { w : |w| mod 3 >= |w| mod 2 }
over the alphabet sigma = {a}

I tried and got the abstract logic . Length where mod 3 < mod 2 is
length should be multiple of 3 but not multiple of 2
If we eliminate those condition
then we get the all cases which satisfies the condition